# Traveling to Brazil but with a layover in the US - two passports

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality

I'm going to Brazil from Canada, but I have a layover in Chicago. When I do my check-in, do I use my Brazilian passport or my Canadian? Can I show the Canadian passport when going to Chicago and show the Brazilian passport when going to Brazil, since in Chicago I will have to check in my luggage again? I'm confused and I called the place bought my tickets from and they said I can't use 2 passports. Has anyone done it?

Answer (score 2):

**If trip is in one booking:**

Show both passports at check-in at the Canadian airport (whilst telling the staff you're going to Brazil via the US), then your Canadian passport at the boarding gate in Canada, and then the Brazilian passport at the boarding gate in Chicago.

**If trip is in separate bookings:**

Show your Canadian passport at check-in and the boarding gate at the Canadian airport, and the Brazilian one at check-in and the boarding gate in Chicago.

**If doing the same trip back:**

Use the Canadian passports at both check-ins and boarding gates, and only use the Brazilian one at Brazilian border control.

Comment: Note that if the OP is flying from a Canadian airport with US preclearance, the first airline might not care about travel documents (other than for identity) as the person would already have "entered" the US prior to boarding the flight.

Comment: @user102008 Check-in is before preclearance though

Comment: but why would the airline care at check-in though, since they are not at risk of having to transport the person back?

Comment: @user102008 Possibly because they would have to load off the baggage if it's clear that the passenger can't clear preclearance. Haven't flown that route though, so don't know